# Gmail auto reply script - how to set conditional time and stop multiple replies?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have adapted a Gmail auto reply script to send emails to people who message me on my non-working days. I would like the script to begin sending replies on a Friday from 16:30, but I'm not sure if my code is correct.

My script did not appear to be sending any replies this past Friday when tested, but was working fine on Saturday, Sunday and Monday.

```
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var minute = date.getMinutes();
  if ([1,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 8) || (day == 5 && hour == 16 && minute >= 30)) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
        threads[i].reply("Hi," + "\n\n Thanks for your email. My working days are Tuesday to Friday, so I won't pick up your message until Tuesday morning.");
      threads[i].markRead();
      threads[i].star();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Additionally, is there any way to adapt my script so that it won't send the auto reply message to senders that have already received it (as with Gmail's standard auto reply feature). I have searched Stack Overflow for this solution, using terms such as 'conditional replies', but to no avail. (I appreciate I may be using the wrong terms entirely!)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to complement your `if` statement by the condition `(day == 5 && hour >= 17)`

To verify either an email has been sent to certain senders already, you can use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service). This allows you to save the senders in cache and to compare for every new email either its sender is already contained in the properties:

```
function autoReply() {
var interval = 5;
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var minute = date.getMinutes();
  if ([1,6,0].indexOf(day) > -1 || (day == 1 && hour < 8) || (day == 5 && hour == 16 && minute >= 30)|| (day == 5 && hour >= 17)){
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
         var sender=threads[i].getMessages()[0].getFrom();
        if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){
           PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('from', '');
         }
        var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('fromArray');
        if(scriptProperties.indexOf(sender)==-1){
          threads[i].reply("Hi," + "\n\n Thanks for your email. My working days are Tuesday to Friday, so I won't pick up your message until Tuesday morning.")
          threads[i].markRead();
          threads[i].star();
          scriptProperties=scriptProperties+sender; 
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('from',  scriptProperties);
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer – that's really helpful!Although I have to confess I'm a little bewildered by PropertiesService. Would I have to specify the sender(s) in the script?

Comment: You can imagine script properties as a variable that continues existing after the script finished and thus, its content can be retrieved during the next script run. The script retrieves `var sender=threads[i].getMessages()[0].getFrom();` for each unread thread it is looping through, checks with indexOf() either this sender is already contained in the script properties. If yes - nothing happens, if no - an email is sent to this sender and his email is added to script properties.

Comment: Is there any way to send the autoreply to specific email addresses only?